# Set Hours does affect the Object

Tags: javascript, object, time

I´m currently facing a strange issue, which i would like to discuss as i don´t understand it.

I have this sample code:

```js
const created_at = new Date();
var myObj = {
 "key": "value",
  "expires_in": 36000
};
Object.assign(myObj, { created_at: created_at});
var expiresInHours = Math.floor(myObj.expires_in / (60 * 60));
console.log(myObj);
var expires_at = created_at.setHours(created_at.getHours() + expiresInHours);
console.log(myObj);
expires_at  = new Date(expires_at);
Object.assign(myObj, { expires_at: expires_at });
console.log(myObj);
```

It seems that the line where `created_at.setHours` does affect my object. Why is the value of `myObj.created_at` the same as `myObj.expires_at` after executing the `.setHours` function and how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

> The setHours() method sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

It explicitly states why it behaves the way you observed.

If you only want to change `expires_at` you'll have to copy `created_at` and then update it.

```js
const created_at = new Date();
var myObj = {
  "key": "value",
  "expires_in": 36000
};
Object.assign(myObj, {
  created_at: created_at
});
var expiresInHours = Math.floor(myObj.expires_in / (60 * 60));
console.log(myObj);
/// Copy and update
var expires_at = new Date(created_at).setHours(created_at.getHours() + expiresInHours);
console.log(myObj);
expires_at = new Date(expires_at);
Object.assign(myObj, {
  expires_at: expires_at
});
console.log(myObj);
```

**EDIT** This seems to be confusion over JavaScript Constants. Again [from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description)

> The **`const` declaration** creates a read-only reference to a value. It does **not** mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.

So, while you can't change the `const` to reference a different value, you can update that values properties.

Comment: Thanks it is working now, even if i still don´t really understand how it is possible that a variable that is declared as constant can be updated. But i will take a deeper look into the documentation. Thanks

Comment: The constant is still referencing the same date object - this is what makes it a constant. Constant doesn't mean that all the properties of the referenced object are locked just that it can't reference another object/value later.

Answer (score 0):

setHours() modifies the date it's called on, then returns the getTime() of the modified object. I think you just need to delete the assignment...

<strike>var expires_at =</strike> expires_at.setHours(created_at.getHours() + expiresInHours);

Answer (score 0):

when you code this line:

```
Object.assign(myObj, { created_at: created_at});
```

`created_at` variable is Compound. Compound values are Pass-by-reference. So when `created_at.setHours` It will change value of key `created_at` in `myObj` object

To fix with your case, you can change with this simple code:

```
//Object.assign(myObj, { created_at: created_at});
Object.assign(myObj, { created_at: new Date()});
```